# Javascript/jQuery: calling function in another frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames

I'm new to the DOM and JavaScript and hitting on some problems when trying to call a function defined in a frame from the context of the top-level frame or Firebug.

Given the below frameset:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <frameset cols="*" rows="81,*">
        <frame id="topFrame" tabindex="1" name="topFrame" noresize="noresize" scrolling="No" src="hometop.aspx"/> 
        <frameset border="0" cols="214,*" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
            <frameset border="0" cols="*" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" rows="70,*">
                <frame tabindex="-1" id="chatFrame" name="chatFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" src=""/>
                <frame tabindex="-1" id="leftFrame" name="leftFrame" noresize="noresize" src="leftFrame.aspx"/>
            </frameset> 
            <frame tabindex="-1" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" src=""/>
        </frameset> 
        <noframes>Your browser does not support frameset.</noframes> 
    </frameset>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to write a javascript hook that will call a javascript function defined in **#leftFrame** when the above document is first opened.  I'm performing this in a Firebug session with ***jQuery*** loaded.

*jQuery("#leftFrame")* returns a frame DOM element.  Now I'd like to execute my function (*openLink*, defined in plain old script tag in leftFrame.aspx) in the context of the frame.  My understanding is that the function will be a DOM node under the *leftFrame*'s document element.  However I can't get hold of the frame's document.

I've tried:

```
 jQuery("#leftFrame").document
 jQuery("#leftFrame").contentDocument
 jQuery("#leftFrame").find("html")
```

Also when inspecting the DOM tree in Firebug I can't see the *openLink* function under any DOM nodes as I'd expect.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#leftFrame')[0].contentWindow.document
$('#leftFrame')[0].contentWindow.functionName()
```

The above should work. jQuery's `contents()` only works on the iframe node so you'll have to reference it like that.

Comment: `contentWindow` is an IE extension not standardised until HTML5 and with support issues in older versions of the other browsers. Typically you should branch code on the presence of the long-standard `contentDocument` property first (and use `defaultView` on it to get the associated `window`), falling back to `contentWindow` for IE6-7.