# jQuery - Call a function in another frame

Tags: jquery

jQuery - How to invoke a function defined in a frame from another frame.

Please see the [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/ajomuc/12/edit#javascript,html). I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501080/javascript-jquery-calling-function-in-another-frame), but couldn't successfully complete it.

**EDIT**

To make it easier to understand, I have put the following code,

```
<frameset rows="25%,*">
  <frame src="framea.html" id="framea"/>
  <frame src="frameb.html" id="frameb"/>
</frameset>
```

**framea.html**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var methoda = function() {
    alert('in method a');
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Frame 1
 </body>
</html>
```

**frameb.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var methodb = function() {
      //$('#framea')[0].contentWindow.methoda();
}

methodb();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Frame 2
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm looking for a jQuery way of invoking the function in another frame.

Comment: Thanks @PoweRoy, I was about to correctly format my question.

Answer (score 0):

[EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) will be suitable for your need.

It makes cross-domain communication easy and the demos are not hard to understand.

Good luck.